# Python - if StringSet has a String in it

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb

I have searched quite thoroughly and have not found a suitable solution. I am new to Python/Programming, so I appreciate any advice I can get:

I am trying to search a string from StringSet, here is what i am trying to do but not getting the value.

```
string_set = {'"123", "456", "789"'}
value = '123'

values_list = []

def fun():
    for i in string_set:
         if i in value:
             output=LookupTables.get('dynamo-table', i, {})
             
    return output

fun()
```

Using the above if it value is in the stringset then it will return the value which is in my dynmodb table.
Nothe: There could be more than 5000 values in my table so i wanted to get earliest possible return.

Comment: Is it intentional that your string_set is just a single string? You are using double string quotes.

Comment: Yes, i have a dynmodb table where i have a values like that 
string_set = {'"123", "456", "789"'}

Comment: Okay I see. But in this case your set just contains one value `"'123", "456", "789"'`

Comment: Do i need to modify my table like this 
```
string_set = {'123, 456, 789'}
```
 beacuse i have to store multiple values in it and then check if the incoming log id is there or  not

Comment: Yeah exactly. You need to split the values up so you can actually look for it.

Comment: it still one value. right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im assuming you're just checking if 123 is in `"123", "456", "789"` since you had it wrapped in single quotes:

to represent that lets use:

```
strset =  {"123", "456", "789"}
```

what if you have to use that weird variable?

this should render it useable

```
strset = {'"123", "456", "789"'}

removed = next(iter(strset))
strset.update((removed).split())
strset.remove(removed)

strset = set([i.strip(",").strip('"') for i in strset])
```

another cleaner way:

```
strset = {'"123", "456", "789"'}

exec(f"strset = {next(iter(strset))}")

print("123" in strset)
```

---

now to check if `value` is in there:

```
if value in strset:
    #do code here
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should romove the extra '' firstly

```py
string_set = {'"123", "456", "789"'}   # this set has just one value '"123", "456", "789"'

string_set_fixed =  {"123", "456", "789"}
```

Comment: what's your dynmodb table's type in python

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
string_set = {"123", "456", "789"}
value = '123'

values_list = []

def fun():
    if value in string_set:
        output = LookupTables.get('dynamo-table', value, {})
    return output

fun()
```

Explanation:

- Your definition of `string_set` contains an extraneous pair of `' '`;
- When you are testing `i in value`, you are comparing `i` against all substrings of `value`, rather than against the whole string.

Comment: my bad but How i can remove extraneous pair of ' ' from my table?

Comment: Oooooh, I didn't understand that this was the problem.